# Effective weight-monodromy conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations, weights, weil-conjectures

$\DeclareMathOperator\Gr{Gr}$Let $G$ be the absolute Galois group of a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with inertia subgroup $I$, and let $V$ be an $\ell$-adic representation of $G$. Grothendieck's Monodromy Theorem says that after passing to an open subgroup of $G$, the action of $I$ is unipotent, and moreover may be described by a nilpotent operator $N \colon V \to V$.

There is a monodromy filtration $M_i V$, such that $N M_i V \subseteq M_{i-2}$ and $N^i \colon \Gr^M_i V \to \Gr^M_{-i} V$ is an isomorphism. The Weight-Monodromy Conjecture states that if $V=H^n(X_{\overline{k}};\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$ for a variety $X$ over a number field $k$, then the Frobenius action on $\Gr^M_i V$ is pure of weight $n+i$ (in particular, the case of good reduction is essentially the Weil conjecture).

Is there a version of this conjecture stating that $\Gr^M_i V = 0$ for $|i| > n$? I can't seem to find that in the literature (e.g., in [Conjecture 1.13 of Scholze](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/PerfectoidSpaces.pdf), or in [Deligne's original article](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Theorie-de-Hodge-I.pdf)).

This is true for abelian varieties, and it seems implied in the literature, but I haven't found a statement like this.

The statement should more generally say that whenever $V$ is an effective motive of weight $n$, the weights are in the interval $[0,2n]$.

Answer (score 11):

You can bound the filtration length (assuming the WM conj) using the weight spectral sequence of Rapoport--Zink. This is a sp seq converging to $H^*(X_{\overline{k}})$; and if the WM conj holds, then the monodromy filtration coincides with the filtration induced by this spectral seq. (There's a nice account of this in Scholl's paper [https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ajs1005/preprints/weil-preprint1.pdf](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Eajs1005/preprints/weil-preprint1.pdf).) The $E_1$ page of the spectral seq is explicitly given in terms of the components of the special fibre of a semistable model, so you can make explicit what region of the plane they're supported in and you get a bound on the length of the filtration. (I haven't checked whether that bound is the one you want though, the indexing is pretty barbarous.)

**Edit**. Prompted by Pol's comment, I did the computation: the $E_1^{ij}$ terms are supported in a parallelogram with vertices at $(0, 0), (0, d), (2d, 0), (2d, -d)$. So in particular the filtration on $H^n$ has at most $1 + \min(n, 2d-n)$ nonzero graded pieces for any $n$.

Comment: The bound is the one you want: If $X_{\overline{k}}$ has dimension $d$ then there are at most $2d+1$ terms on the $E_1$ page of the weight specral sequence that contribue to a single degree of cohomology, and each of these terms is pure of a weight between $0$ and $2d$. For instance, there are 3 terms contributing to the middle degree cohomology of a curve with semistable reduction, and the possible weights are $0,1,2$. In this case the weight-monodromy conjecture is known.